# Change site title color on individual pages

Tags: theme-development, css

Hi I've asked this question in the main stackoverlow section and have got several answers which sadly have not solved my issue (unless I am doing something wrong).  So in a last ditch attempt hopefully i will get a more specific response by posting here in a more tailored section.....blabbering on.

Site : http://www.otislandscapedesign.com/

Is it possible to change color of the main title of the site without changing the color of other pages/posts on the site ? (if that makes sense).

I would like the 'Otis landscape design landscape architect & designer to be in white font and all other pages/posts/categories to remain in black font.

Just a heads up I am looking for a CSS solution as i am not clued up in php :O

Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: would be hard without PHP.  Your code shows that it's inversed though, so you may have a theme setting or on your individual page edit you may have the option.    Doing it with PHP will be very easy though...just one if then statement.  Let me know if you change your mind.

Comment: I had a feeling php would be the only way as someone else stated. As i have not created a child theme, is it possible to push PHP via a PHP plugin ?

Comment: why not use php?  it will solve your problem pretty easy.  no special trickery will be involved.  Do you have access to your header.php?

Comment: If the theme is any good, you should find the Home class on the Body tag. You van use that in css to changes the title on the home page only

Comment: (im not rehearsed on php) But i'll give it a shot with guidance. Do I access the Editor> Theme Header ?

Comment: try the css below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack  i missed it.

Just add this css

```
//changes site title and slogan
.home .gk-logo-text.inverse > span {
    color: white!important;
}

//changes site slogan only
.home .gk-logo-text.inverse > span + span {
    color: white!important;
}
```

thanks @cjbj

Comment: wow...incredible, I've seen users write this same code but in different ways and the one you gave nailed it to a T.  Thank you so much and everyone that contributed above.